# How to use round and trunc to get dd:mm:yy:hh

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am using oracle 11g and I have normal timestamps (starttime) which produce an output as follows:

```
 23.09.14 05:15:00,000000000
```

Now I want an output like

```
23.09.14 05
```

Also ok would be:

```
23.09.14 05:00:00,000000000
```

but when I use something like

`round(starttime, 'HH') or trunc(starttime ,'HH24')` I always get

```
23.09.14
```

with no hours at all.

Looking around here at stackoverflow I found

```
substr(TO_CHAR(starttime),0,LENGTH(TO_CHAR(starttime))-13)
```

which produces the correct output as char but when I want to sort dates it wont work because it sorts alphabetically. (so for example, 1.3., 1.4, 1.5.... instead of 1.3., 2.3., 3.3,...),

Any idea how I can get a timestamp which is rounded to the full hour?

I will have to use the statement in a group by clause. The complete statement would look like:

```
select round(starttime, 'HH24'), sum(counter) from wmsconsolidationorderdwct group by round(starttime, 'HH24') order by round(starttime, 'HH24') desc;
```

So I cannot display the rounded time and sort by the full timestamp since this would violate the group by clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will truncate to the hour:

```
trunc(SYSTIMESTAMP) + extract(hour from SYSTIMESTAMP)/24
```

Edit:

I just tried it and

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP ,'HH24') FROM DUAL;
```

returns the correct result.

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7/1298)

Comment: The first line works for me. Thank you! The second does not in my case.

Comment: @user1093356 I don't think you need the first query. The second query is correct.

Answer (score 1):

- If your purpose is to display, then use **TO_CHAR** with desired **format model**.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'DD.MM.YY HH24') FROM dual;

TO_CHAR(SYS
-----------
28.05.15 15

SQL>
```

- If your purpose is to do **date arithmetic** then you need to leave the data type as date.

For example,

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
  2  /

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP ,'HH24') FROM DUAL
  2  /

TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP,
-------------------
28-05-2015 15:00:00

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a timestamp object:

```
select my_number from(
  SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (SYSTIMESTAMP, 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI'),
        'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI'
       ),'HH24')) AS my_number
 FROM DUAL)
order by 1
```

This could be simplified to:

```
select my_number from(
  SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'HH24')) AS my_number
FROM DUAL)
order by 1
```

Comment: That produces the same output as substr(TO_CHAR(starttime),0,LENGTH(TO_CHAR(starttime))-13). It is a char object which looks like I want it to look but I gets sorted alphabetically and not like dates / timestamps.

Comment: I have edited my question. There is also a group by clause needed so I cannot sort by timestamp since it is not part of the group clause.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Create that query as an in-line view and then order that query after you've grouped.